# Run an interactive shell command from PHP in CLI mode

Tags: php, bash, shell, interactive

I have a PHP CLI script and want to execute an interactive bash command (e.g. `less huge-file.txt`) from that script and get the same view (with `less` e.g. the navigation controls) as if I had started it directly from the terminal.

The normal `system()` call is not enough because they don't *pause* and just return all the output at once (in the case of e.g. `less`).

Sense is that I have a CLI script that organises several tasks. Some of them use complex bash commands and I just want to invoke the bash scripts from PHP but get the original terminal behaviour.

Comment: that's nice. Good luck with that (even though it's not possible unless you're running PHP in cli mode)... Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do/requirements lists.

Comment: @MarcB I thought more generic questions are better? I was struggling to find a good and short solution, so I thought I would be good to share my findings ans also ask for better ones?

Comment: @thatotherguy I have a CLI script and don't need any web access. I reworded the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Ah ok, then never mind

Answer (score 1):

```
proc_open( 'less huge-file.txt', array( STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR), $pipes);
```

This calls the command and passes all controls etc. through, so that there is no distinction to a normal `less huge-file.txt`.

Still a bit clunky but a lot shorter compared to other examples I could find.

Comment: @hek2mgl Hm, maybe it depends on the environment? For me with PHP 7 CLI on Mac OS 10.9.5 it works fine.

Comment: I've used php5.6 for the test. I'll give php7 a try in the evening .

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

I doubt you are really looking to script using less (that will get ugly, head / tail / sed /awk are your friends in text manipulation), but getting a real shell behavior is very possible.

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', false);

//open file in less. $return1 will contain the view and the first part of the file you opened. The second argument is needed to delimit the return since less will not end in a shell prompt.
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('less /path/to/huge-file.txt', 'huge-file.txt');

//quit less, you must do this or the shell will hang on the less prompt and will have to be forcefully terminated.
$return2  = $shell->exeCmd('q');
```